# Erase old dump tape in Tru64 UNIX

Tags: unix, tape

We backup our OLD Tru64 UNIX system (Digital UNIX 4.0F) to DDS3 tapes using the `dump` command.  We want to recycle those tapes to make future backups on when they get too old.  I've found the `mt erase` command won't erase them, probably because the dump command puts blocks on the tape and it's no longer raw.

What's a simple way to erase the tape?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually with tape devices you don't have to do anything special to overwrite them - simply start writing again from the beginning of the tape, and whatever was already on there is gone.

As [a FAQ for one classic backup program](http://wiki.zmanda.com/index.php/FAQ:Why_does_Amanda_not_append_to_a_tape%3F) notes, the problem is usually the *reverse*: most tape devices are so keen to rewind to BOT and start overwriting their payload, that considerable design and implementation effort is expended on preventing them from doing exactly that:

> When appending to a tape, there is the possibility that, between the
>   time that Amanda positions to the last image (that already is not
>   really trivial!), and opening the device for writing, a tape rewind
>   happens, and in that case Amanda would happily erase ALL of the tape,
>   containing possibly many days worth of backup.

(AMANDA solved that problem by simply never appending to a tape - you write everything you're going to write to that tape in a single pass during which time the device is kept locked.  Draconian and wasteful, yes, but that gives you some idea how easy it is to accidentally rewind and overwrite a tape!)

I would advise against degaussing for anything except secure destruction (and I wouldn't rely on it for that, either).  [As Wikipedia notes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degaussing#Irreversible_damage_to_some_media_types):

> For certain forms of computer data storage, however, such as modern
>   hard drives and some tape backup drives, degaussing renders the
>   magnetic media completely unusable and damages the storage system.
>   This is due to the devices having an infinitely variable read/write
>   head positioning mechanism which relies on special servo control data
>   (e.g. Gray Code) that is meant to be permanently embedded into the
>   magnetic media.
>
> [...]
>
> The servo patterns are normally never
>   overwritten by the device for any reason and are used to precisely
>   position the read/write heads over data tracks on the media, to
>   compensate for sudden jarring device movements, thermal expansion, or
>   changes in orientation. Degaussing indiscriminately removes not only
>   the stored data but also the servo control data, and without the servo
>   data the device is no longer able to determine where data is to be
>   read or written on the magnetic medium.

though I freely admit I don't know whether DDS-3 is one such medium.

Comment: Yep, writing over seemed to work just fine, just not sure if we write a smaller amount to the tape than what is on it, whether the rest will still be there (visibly).

Comment: Theoretically, it is, but when you overwrite a tape a new EOT marker is written where you stop laying down the new data.  Is is *extremely* hard to persuade a tape drive to read past that, eg to get data from a previously-full tape which has had a small block accidentally written to the top of it - I know of noone who's managed it, and God knows, most of us old-timers have at one time or another had to try.  If that concerns you, should be encrypting your backups.

Answer (score 0):

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/TAPEDEVICE bs=1024
```

or you can probably use a similar tar command to create an archive on the tape device from /dev/null

Comment: Well so far, that command has been running over 16 hours, so I'm still waiting to see if it works out.

Comment: I finally broke out of that command, and tried a `tcopy` to check the results, and that command ended up timing out (where it had always worked before).  Guess I'll just try the overwrite strategy.

Comment: That is the major drawback of this approach but there aren't alot of options unless you have physical access to the tapes and can de-mag them or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Try getting hold of a degausser (you just put the tape on it switch on and in a few seconds it's erased). Saves you the time of loading tapes up just to delete them.

I don't mean to be rude but I have to ask:  Are you adminstering this system through a hole in time to 1995?

Comment: He wouldn't be the only person with on old DEC Alpha sitting around; they were (generally speaking) solidly engineered machines at the time. Admittedly, that was a long time ago but with the architecture, OS, and (possibly) third-party tools and libraries no longer existing it's not surprising that some people run them into the ground.

Comment: Yes, definitely a hole in time (1999).  We're an industrial system that can't be upgraded without upgrading the million dollar system it's attached to, which thankfully will be done in the next few years.